# how to test different style of a spannable (Android)?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, spannable

I would like to test with espresso a spannable containing two strings with different colors. With no success ....

here is my span.

```java
Spanny spannyBullet1 = new Spanny(getString(R.string.cb1_spannybullet1_first),
                    new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.grey_dark)))
                    .append(getString(R.string.cb1_spannybullet1_end),
                            new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.blue_light)),
                            new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL));
```

Here is my test:

```java
@Test
public void moveToCB2Fragment() {
 onView(withId(R.id.txv_bullet_1)).check(matches(withText(startsWith("text1")))).check(matches(hasTextColor(R.color.grey_dark)));;
        onView(withId(R.id.txv_bullet_1)).check(matches(withText(endsWith(" text2"))));
```

I tried also with a custom espresso matcher like this :

```java
onView(withText(startsWith("text1"))).check(matches(withHintTextColor(R.color.grey_dark)));
```

```java
class HintTextColorMatcher extends BoundedMatcher<View, TextView> {

    private final int color;

    public HintTextColorMatcher(@ColorRes int color) {
        super(TextView.class);
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(TextView item) {
        return item.getCurrentHintTextColor() == color;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("with hint text color:")
                .appendValue(color);
    }
}
```

Futhermore do you think is possible to use startswith and endswith with @StringRes ?

I tried to use context in orter to have context.getstring(R.string.text1) without success ...

thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: unfortunately not yet.